# Float value gets incremented by 2 [ANDROID]

Tags: android, type-conversion

In my app, i am getting some item price from web in double, then i have to multiply it with item quantity and display on a textview.
The original value in double is ***0.65340002596378299*** 
As i want it as 0.65 only i use this statement for this purpose

```
float itemprice = Float.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", price));
```

Next when i multiplied it with 6(quantity of item) i got this result ***3.8999999***

```
 float total=no_of_items*itemprice;
```

So i used Math.round function to get my required result which is **0.65*6=3.90**

```
float total=Math.round(((no_of_items * itemprice) * 100.0) / 100.0);
```

and i got 4.0 as final result but i want exact 3.90
How this can be achieved?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Obviously you should learn some basics ... you may obviously use Math.round after you mutiply it by N and then divide it by N where N is 10^k for get accuracy of k decimal places  `double N = 10^k; double rounded = Math.round(price * N)/N;`... also double may be 3.9 but you can show it as 3.90 with right formating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this its result is 3.9 :

```
 double price = 0.65340002596378299;
 float itemprice = Float.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", price));
 float no_of_items = 6;
 float total=(no_of_items * itemprice);
 float itemp = Float.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", total));
```

Comment: result is 3.9, it should be 3.90

Comment: @User i have edited my answer it giving 3.9 as you want

Comment: @User to keep your number to twi decimal point you can use this
`new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(doubleValue)`

Comment: `Float.valueOf(String.format(..))` using to string and then parse it back is terrible idea ... that's how bad apps are made